# Emacs : problem with tags file?

Tags: emacs, cygwin, ctags, etag

I am using ctags to create tags for my Emacs to read symbols from, using cygwin.

Emacs says ***"visit-tags-table-buffer: File /home/superman/tags is not a valid tags table"***

here are my options to find files and generate tags.

```
$>find . -type f -regex '.*\.[hc]\|.*\.cpp' -print0 |
  xargs -0 ctags -e --extra=+q --fields=+fksaiS --c++-kinds=+px --append -f ~/tags
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think "ctags" is the wrong program.  (I'm not sure what it's for; I suspect it's obsolete).

Emacs should have come with a program called "etags"; use that instead.

Comment: yep, after a lot of reading I think I am using the wrong one, I should be using Exuberant Ctags, and not the original Ctags. let me try and let you know. thanks :-) !

Comment: for C/C++ I think, that gtags from GNU Global package is better (you also need to load gtags.el)

Comment: Thanks @Peter !
RT@Alex - I did not know about gtags, will take a look, thanks a lot.

Comment: Alex, it looks promising. are you using it, how do you like it?, I am just starting to use Emacs, so with your advice, I will switch to gtags. thanks a lot. let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog post](http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-tags-in-emacs-on-windows.html) on using etags with emacs that should help

Comment: this is cool ! I did it with cygwin. can you add another tag ("Using etags in Emacs with cygwin") for google to bump up this post ? this is really helpful and neat.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I need to use **Exuberant Ctags** and not **Ctags**. I did not know that they were two different products.

So, DO NOT get Ctags from Cygwin's repository, instead go here [**Exuberant Ctags**](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) if you want to use it with Emacs. Ctags does not work with Emacs.

Comment: The version of ctags in Cygwin *is* Exuberant CTags (see 'man ctags').  You can either run it as "ctags -e" or "etags" to get the correct behavior.